# Access of computed property/element. Indexable signature not found in HTMLElement

Tags: flowtype

I am using this snippet to get size of the viewport

```
function getViewport(): { width: number, height: number } {
  let e = window;
  let a = 'inner';

  if (!('innerWidth' in window)) {
    a = 'client';
    e = document.documentElement || document.body;
  }

  return {
    width: e[`${a}Width`],
    height: e[`${a}Height`],
  };
}
```

but when i run `flow check` i am getting this error:

```
 18:     height: e[`${a}Height`],
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ access of computed property/element. Indexable signature not found in
 18:     height: e[`${a}Height`],
                 ^ HTMLElement
```

i just started learning flow so if someone would explain me how can i fix this or point me to the docs when I can read more about it that would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you want to do, but easier workaround would be:

`let e: Object = window;`